# Is there a nice operator to construct a string from Observable<List<String>> using 1 buffer only?

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

```
Observable<List<String>> listOfCsvValues = Observable.just(["id", "name"], [2, "messi"], ...)
```

I'd probably use the following construction but it'll create some temporary buffers (every `String.join()` will basically call `buffer.toString()` in the end):

```
.map(values -> String.join(",", values))
                .toList()
                .map(records -> String.join("\n", records));
```

What I really want is to have 1 huge buffer only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collect it:

```java
listOfCsvValues
    .collect(() -> new StringBuilder(),
        (builder, list) -> {
            if (builder.length() > 0) {
                builder.append('\n');
            }
            boolean separate = false;
            for (Object o : list) {
                if (separate) {
                    builder.append(',');
                } else {
                    separate = true;
                }
                builder.append(o);
            }
        }
    )
    .map(Object::toString)
```